# social media feed generation Redis MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, redis, feed

So I've been reading a ton about feed generation at scale but unfortunately I'm not too technically minded and need confirmation / advice when it comes to creating a somewhat scalable feed generation microservice.

I'm developing a niche social network site with 300-400~ active daily users, who are typically all friends with each other, and I need a way to efficiently generate feeds and fan them out to each follower of the author.

My thought process is currently:

- Author posts a status
- A single copy of the status is stored in a MySQL table
- Each follower(user) have their own feed, which will be stored in a single table in memory with Redis, containing an id of the follower and the id of the status
- When a follower requests their feed the meta data from Redis is retrieved and used to search the MySQL status table
- MySQL statuses returned
- If there is no feed cached then one will be generated through MySQL friendship tables and the statuses table, and then stored in Redis

What are the drawbacks to this and are there any blatantly better methods? This way, I don't have to repeatedly query every single friend and their posts when the user reloads their page and can instead query the posts directly based from the cached feed metadata